# Select word and surrounding words with window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript

Using `window.getSelection()` I want to get a word selected at position `n` but also the words at positions `n-1` and `n+1`.

For example:

`this is a sentence`

highlighted: `is`

word n-1: `this`

word n + 1: `a`

I understand how to do this with regex, but how can I do this kind of thing with `window.getSelection()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the structure of the HTML page? Do you control it?
If not, this could be difficult.

If the selection is in one element on the page, this can be done with the help of the selected range object:

var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

It has properties with the starting position, end position and the text of the element that the selection is in.

Then you can break the text by spaces before and after the selection position  and get the word before and after the selected word.

```
var allWordsBefore = range.startContainer.wholeText.substr(0, range.startOffset).trim().split(' ');
var prevWord = allWordsBefore[allWordsBefore.length-1];
```

Similarly you can get the word after the selection.

Comment: This method fails if you use double click to select a whole paragraph. However, it doesn't fail if you just select dragging the mouse. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: you need to compare the properties of window.getSelection() for the two cases. I'm not sure why this is so but you can detect the situation of triple click to select a whole paragraph and use a modified code in that case. I think the parameter you should use to detect that this is the situation is that the focus node or the extent node is not the same as the anchor node.